# how can I display and load audio files from iOS app resource/asset folder?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am fresh to programming and have chosen to learn swift as my first language. I have started playing with the AVFoundation framework. In this case I am working with AVAudioPlayer.

I currently have audio files being loaded through NSURL using the file name and type but I would like to be able to load audio files for each instance of AVAudioPlayer from a list or menu that displays the files currently in the app's resource folder.

This is how I am currently loading my audio files:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:     NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource( "test_kick", ofType: "wav")!),    error: nil)
```

I have searched for hours with no luck and really don't know where to start with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simon, I don't think an Asset Catalog is supposed to be used for Audio Files... Why are you using this method specifically?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Shai. Sorry I was not specific. I mean I would like to load from my supporting files rather than Asset Catalog. I have a number of .wav files in my supporting files folder within xcode and I would like to be able to select which one I load to AVAudioPlayer from within the app I am building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simon, if I understand your question right, you know how to load a file from the assets, but you want to show a list of the files and play it after a click on a specific file, is that right?

Therefore you will first have to list the folder contents in an UITableView, and react on the click from that TableView to load the selected file into your AVPlayer...

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("your path", error: nil)
```

The above code will give you an array of files inside the path you already have, to be represented in an UITableView

Do you know how to build up a UITableViewDataSource and Delegate?

Comment: Hi Neo, thank you for your reply. That is right, I know how to load a file. UITableView is new to me, will be my next step. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, I guess the 'easies' way would be if you drag and drop a UITableViewController in your StoryBoard and give it a newly created UITableViewController Class... Then you see the code you need in front of you and can learn from Apples code snippet... If you have further question on this, write me here, I come back from day to day...

Comment: Thank you! Just sending me in the right direction is a huge help at this point. I am really new to this so a lot to learn.

Comment: Table views are confusing at first. I suggest finding a tutorial on using them and going through it. Just about everybody gets cell reuse wrong the first time they do it (me included!) Most of the resources I know off the top of my head are Objective-C though, so would not be helpful to a beginner that doesn't know that language.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Duncan, working through a tutorial and will keep cell reuse in mind. Cheers.